# Delete multiple keyframes at a time?

Tags: keyframes

How do you delete multiple keyframes at a time? Pressing space and having to click buttons seems inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

In the graph editor or dope sheet select all of the keyframes you want to delete and then you can delete all selected items at once.

Answer (score 2):

In the *Dopesheet* you can select the keyframes you want either with <kbd>cmd</kbd> *right click*, or <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> *right click* to select several keyframes.

Of course <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, and again <kbd>A</kbd> to deselect all, and <kbd>X</kbd> to delete.

You can also select with one of the selection tools you already use in the 3D view: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> for the lasso, <kbd>B</kbd> for the box, and <kbd>C</kbd> for the pen.

Also you can put the green line wherever you want, if you <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + *right click* on the right of the line you will select all the keyframes on the right of the line, if you <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + *right click* on the left of the line you will select all the keyframes on the left of the line.

Also note that the arrow button on the bottom horizontal menu of the Dopesheet window (*Only Include Channels Relating To Selected Objects And Data*) allows you to display only the keyframes of the object you've selected in the 3D view.